# Firebase transaction “maxretry”

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

Wasted 3 hours already - trying to run transaction in firebase but it always fails with maxretry.

Basically my flow is:

On client:

1. call firebase http cloud funciton using js sdk.

On server:

2. read data from data base
3. update/invalidate data if needed
4. write the data back using transaction

The problem - step 4 always fail with maxretry.

The simplified code:

```
exports.myMethod2 = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    utilsModule.throwIfNoAuth(context);
    return methodWithTransaction(context, admin);
});

exports.methodWithTransaction = function (context, admin) {
    //this is called only once from outside!
    return rootRef.child("my/data/path").once("value")
        .then(function (indexRef) {
            var usageObj = indexRef.val();
            //update object's state
            usageObj =
                {
                    timestampUtcArray: [1530656089821, 1530656089822],
                    itemsCount: 2,
                    writeTimestamp: 1530656502759
                }
            return usageObj;
        })
        .then(function (usageObj) {
            //her eis the sad part...
            return rootRef.child("my/data/path").transaction(data => {
                //this method always run 25 times and fails.
                //data aways != usageObj though accross the calls usageObj are the same as well data are the same:
                // usageObj =
                //     {
                //         timestampUtcArray: [1530656089821, 1530656089822],
                //         itemsCount: 2,
                //         writeTimestamp: 1530656502759 <-- only timestamp is different
                //     }
                // data =
                //     {
                //         timestampUtcArray: [1530656089821, 1530656089822],
                //         itemsCount: 2,
                //         writeTimestamp: 1530656503421 <-- only timestamp is different
                //     }

                return usageObj;
            }
        })

}
```

Any input s much appreciated as this seems to be a trivial task but I just stuck...

Comment: Besides the missing parens for the transaction() call, does it give more info if you pass in the second onComplete function and check the Error argument? [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction). A second thought, in case you only need to update a single field (vs the whole object) could you adjust the transaction ref to only hit that field?

Comment: What if you just drop the `once()` call and rely solely on the `transaction()` call? That is the right way to implement this use case anyway. You read the "current" state of the reference in the transaction (it is passed into scope via `data`), and then atomically update it.

Comment: @uncleoptimus - thanks for the tip. Unfortunately onComplete does't provide any useful info here. Also I need to change the whole object

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka - thanks, that actually makes sense - I'll try that. Still not sure why the example above fails...